# How Install beta release of Varnish Cache (varnish-4.1.3-beta1)

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

What I need to do to install varnish-4.1.3-beta1 in a CentOS 7?

Since I don't find the rpm in the [repo](https://repo.varnish-cache.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Lasse Karstensen from Varnish support, follows the rpm for installation:

https://jenkins.varnish-software.com/view/VC4/job/VC4-rpm-el7/

(more specific:
https://jenkins.varnish-software.com/view/VC4/job/VC4-rpm-el7/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/rpm-build/varnish-4.1/el7/ )

Installation Procedure:

- Download all the files except the .src.rpm one.
- Use: `rpm -Uvh` to install

Answer (score 0):

You can compile varnish from source using the instructions found in the [varnish documentation](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/installation/install.html#compiling-varnish-from-source).